# Checking to see if is a normal magic square in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having problems with this last part of code. I get no errors but I do not get the exact desired output.

I'm trying to get the output for the second 2D array(square1) to print out "Is a normal magic square" but it will only recognize it as a magic square and I'm using a text editor (SciTE) which is making it more difficult for me to see where the issue is. I believe the problem is due to the last return statement which I believe returns false but i'm not sure how to get around this. I'm rather new to java. Any help is appreciated!

This is the block of code that seems to be having the problem:

```
    public static boolean isNormalMagicSquare(int[][] array) {
    // Checks to see if magic square is a normal magic square with accumulators for accumulated indeces and sum of actual array

        int sum = 0;
        int total = 0;
        // x gives the desired ending length
        int x = array.length * array.length;
        // iterates to find 
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            total += i;
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                sum = sum + array[i][j];
                if (sum != total) {
                    return false;
                }
            //return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }
```

This is the output I get when running the code which works for the first 2D array and the last 2D array but not the second 2D array(square1):

```
>java -cp . magicSquares
Is not a magic square
Is a magic square
Is a magic square
>Exit code: 0
```

This is where that block of code comes from (I know it's not pretty but it works) also we're required to use all of the methods as stated by my professor:

```
public class magicSquares {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int [][] square = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    if (isNormalMagicSquare(square)) {
        System.out.println("Is a normal magic square");
    }
    else if (isMagicSquare(square)) {
        System.out.println("Is a magic square");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Is not a magic square");



    int [][] square1 = {{2,7,6}, {9,5,1}, {4,3,8}};
    if (isNormalMagicSquare(square1)) {
        System.out.println("Is a normal magic square");
    }
    else if (isMagicSquare(square1)) {
        System.out.println("Is a magic square");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Is not a magic square");


    int [][] square2 = {{8,11,14,1}, {13,2,7,12}, {3,16,9,6}, {10,5,4,15}};
    isNormalMagicSquare(square2);

    if (isNormalMagicSquare(square2)) {
        System.out.println("Is a normal magic square");
    }
    else if (isMagicSquare(square2)) {
        System.out.println("Is a magic square");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Is not a magic square");

    }


// method that calculates the magic sum number
public static int magicSum(int[][] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    //int M = 0;
    int M = n * (n * n + 1) / 2;
    //System.out.print(M);
return M;
}

public static boolean rowsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(int[][] array) {
    int M = magicSum(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int temp = getSumOfRow(array, i);
        if (M != temp) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(int[][] array) {
    int M = magicSum(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int temp = getColumn(array, i);
        if (M != temp) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean diagonalsAreBothEqualToMagicSum (int[][] array) {
    int k =magicSum(array);
    if (getSumOfDownDiagonal(array) ==k && getSumOfUpDiagonal(array)==k) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// method that checks to see if magic sum is equal for all rows, columns, and diagonals
public static boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] array) {
    if (rowsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(array) && columnsAreAllEqualToMagicSum(array) && diagonalsAreBothEqualToMagicSum(array)) {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    return false;
}

public static boolean isNormalMagicSquare(int[][] array) {
    // Checks to see if magic square is a normal magic square with accumulators for accumulated indeces and sum of actual array

        int sum = 0;
        int total = 0;
        // x gives the desired ending length
        int x = array.length * array.length;
        // iterates to find 
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            total += i;
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                sum = sum + array[i][j];
                if (sum != total) {
                    return false;
                }
            //return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }

public static int getSumOfDownDiagonal(int[][] array) {
    //initializes an accumulator and loops through to add the down diagonal
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total = total + array[i][i];
        //System.out.println(array[i][i]);
    }
    return total;
    //System.out.println(total);
}

public static int getSumOfUpDiagonal(int[][] array) {
    // initializes an accumulator and loops through to add the up diagonal
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            total = total + array[i][array.length - 1 -i];
            //System.out.println(array[i][array.length - 1 -i] + " ");
    }
    return total;
}

public static int getSumOfRow(int[][] array, int index) {
    // accumulates and iterates through to add each row in array
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += array[index][i];
    }
    return total;
}

public static int getColumn(int[][] array, int index) {
    // declares a new array and iterates through to add each column
    int[] single = new int[array.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        single[i] = array[i][index];
    }
    int sum = getSumOfColumn(single);
    return sum;
}

public static int getSumOfColumn(int[] array) {
    // getSumOfColumn method accumulates the specified indexes (column)     
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += array[i];
    }
    return total;
}
}
```

Comment: I dont uderstand why did you just put the  `isNormalMagicSquare(square1);` before every `if` check ?

Comment: that was my bad. Thank you for seeing that.

Comment: could you define what is **Normal magic square** and **magic square**. So far I read your code I find the output is okay

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square, a little hard to define so I put the wiki link in there

Comment: The second 2D array is suppose to be a normal magic square because it uses all the integers from 1 to (array.length ^ 2) in a 3x3 matrix = 9 total indices using the integers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Where as the third 2D array has all different integers but form a magic square because the rows, columns, and diagonals all equal the magic sum.